# Change word to Title case not working iOS 15

Tags: iphone, ios, autocorrect, case

I used to be able to select a word, press the shift key and change to the word to Title case by selecting the word in the grey predictive text banner just above keyboard. But this feature does not seem to be working in iOS 15 using iPhone 12. Is there a way to get this working or any other way to quickly change the case of words?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of this existing as a system wide thing, but maybe you're asking about doing this within a particular app. I know you can do this in Pages by selecting text, tapping the paintbrush icon, then the three dots at the right of the font menu.

[image]
[image]